# Divisibility of functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, divisibility

For which $n \in \mathbb{N} $ is $z^{4n}-z^{3n}+z^{2n}-z^{n}+1$ divisible by $z^{4}-z^{3}+z^{2}-z^{1}+1$

I tried factoring the second function and then fill the answer in the first function, but there weren't 'good' solutions to the second function. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: "Is there another way...".  Yes, explore the cases of $n=2, n=3, n=4$ separately.  In each case do *polynomial long division* and see what happens.  Look for a pattern.  Form a hypothesis.  Then try to prove the hypothesis.  Also, regardless of what comes of the cases $n=2, n=3, n=4,$ edit your query to show your work.

Comment: Related [Prove that $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 \mid x^{4n}+x^{3n}+x^{2n}+x^n+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515618)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z^4-z^3+z^2-z+1=\frac{z^5+1}{z+1}=(z+\zeta)(z+\zeta^3)(z+\zeta^3)(z+\zeta^4)$$
where $\zeta=\exp(2\pi i/5)$
So a polynomial $f(z)$ is divisible by $z^4-z^3+z^2-z+1$ iff $f(-\zeta)=f(-\zeta^2)=
f(-\zeta^3)=f(-\zeta^4)=0$. If $f$ has rational coefficients then $f(-\zeta)=0$
suffices. Here
$$f(z)=\frac{z^{5n}+1}{z^n+1}$$
in which form it's easy to find $f(-\zeta)$ unless the denominator happens to be zero.